# If Not Isempty returns "" value but continues to the next statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, is-empty

this codes checks column G and if the value of it is "Test" gets the corresponding value at column E and pastes it to the next row.

```
 Sub FindOpcode_Placepart()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim destCol_part As Integer, destRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String
Dim destRowValue As String

sourceCol_opcde = 7   ' find last row in column E
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol_opcde).End(xlUp).Row
destCol_part = 5
destRow = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol_opcde).End(xlUp).Row


'for every row, find the Opcode
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    If Cells(currentRow, sourceCol_opcde).Value = "Test" Then
        destRowValue = Cells(currentRow, destCol_part).Text


            If Not IsEmpty(destRowValue) Then ' this code returns "" value but proceeds with the next statement.

             destRow = currentRow + 1
             While Cells(destRow, sourceCol_opcde).Value = "Use-Limit"
                    Cells(destRow, destCol_part).Value = destRowValue
                    destRow = destRow + 1
            Wend

        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[IsEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445044(v=vs.60).aspx) isn't a check to see if a Cell has a value, it's a check to see if the ***variable has been initialized***.

```
'Note lack of Option Explicit.

Private Sub Example()
    Debug.Print IsEmpty(foo)    'True.
    foo = 42
    Debug.Print IsEmpty(foo)    'False.
End Sub
```

In the code from the question, `destRowValue` is initialized with `Dim destRowValue As String`.  To check whether a cell has a value or not, you need to test against `vbNullString`...

```
If Cells(currentRow, destCol_part).Text = vbNullString Then
```

...although keep in mind that if you have the possibility of a function in the target cell you might also want to test for IsError:

```
If Not IsError(Cells(currentRow, destCol_part)) And _
       Cells(currentRow, destCol_part).Text = vbNullString Then
```

Because...

```
Cells(1, 1).Value = "=SomefunctionThatDoesntExist"
Debug.Print Cells(1, 1).Text    'Returns "#NAME?"
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. :)  I am loving this site!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
If Not IsEmpty(destRowValue) Then
```

with

```
If destRowValue <> "" Then
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Kindly mark it as answer if it solves your solution.