# Doesn't take value from first column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a dilemma. I have other code that moves some values to the right, so I can enter new data. Using the code that moves the data over, this code doesn't take the data from the first column even though there is data there. It works fine without moving the data over. The code below is part of a copy and paste into a text field. I'm sorry if I explained this bad.

```
Dim LabValues As String
Dim LabColumns As Integer
Dim LabCounter As Integer
Dim EmptyRow As Integer

    Private Function tpnForm(LabValues As String)

    '**Volume*
    EmptyRow = Cells(34, 10).Value2 + Cells(34, 11).Value2 + Cells(34, 12).Value2 + Cells(34, 13).Value2 + Cells(34, 14).Value2 + Cells(34, 15).Value2 + Cells(34, 16).Value2

    If EmptyRow > 0 Then
        LabValues = LabValues & "Volume:       "
        LabColumns = 10

        Do Until LabColumns = 17
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(2, LabColumns)) Then
                If Cells(34, LabColumns).Value > 0 Then
                    LabValues = LabValues & Cells(34, LabColumns).Value & "                "
                Else
                    LabValues = LabValues & "                        "
                End If
            End If
            LabColumns = LabColumns + 1
        Loop
        LabValues = LabValues & vbNewLine
    End If                  

End Function
```

[image of entered data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt96r.pn) If I hit "Full/Lab Move" or "Full/No Labs Move" this makes a new tab and names it. Also moves the data over to the right, so I can enter new data from a different date. "HCN Note" allows the user to take all the data from the yellow fields and make a copy and paste note.

```
Sub CopySheet()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, nws As Worksheet

    'set up
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    'Create a copy of the worksheet
    ws.Copy wb.Worksheets(1) 'places the worksheet at the front
    Set nws = wb.Worksheets(1) 'References the new front worksheet
    'set a name for the new sheet for easy reference
    nws.Name = InputBox("Enter Assessment Date mmddyy")

    'Print out the actual value you want rather than copy and paste.
'****Copy Assessment Date to the Nourish Report Printable****
    nws.Range("V96").Value = ws.Range("C74").Value
'*****Copy Subjective to to New Sheet****
    nws.Range("A41:F47").Value = ws.Range("A41:F47").Value
'******Copy Nutritionally Pertinent Meds to the New Sheet*****
    nws.Range("A50:F50").Value = ws.Range("A50:F50").Value
'******Copy Assessment / Nutrition Diagnosis to New Sheet*****A53:F56
    nws.Range("A53:F56").Value = ws.Range("A53:F56").Value
'*****Copy Nutrition Therapy Goals to New Sheet******A59:F63
    nws.Range("A59:F63").Value = ws.Range("A59:F63").Value
'******Copy Plan of Care to New Sheet******A66:F72
    nws.Range("A66:F72").Value = ws.Range("A66:F72").Value

'******Delete Weight*****
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Subjective****
    Range("A41").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Assessment / Nutrition Diagnosis*****
    Range("A53").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Nutrition Therapy Goals****
    Range("A59").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'***Delete Plan of Care Recommendations****
    Range("A66").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Education*****
    Range("B75").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Discussed With****
    Range("B76").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Last Evaluation Completed On****
    Range("D79").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Assessment Type****
    Range("B21").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'******Delete Oral / Tube Feedings ****
 Range("D25").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D27").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("D29").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
'*****Delete Today's Date****
    Range("C74").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("F12").Select
    Sheets("New").Select
    Range("F12").Select


'***Move Labs over right****
    Worksheets("New").Select
    Range("J2:O12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J2:J12").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("J14:O29").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("K14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J14:J29").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    Range("K34:O41").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L34").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Range("K34").Value = Range("J34").Value
    Range("K35").Value = Range("J35").Value
    Range("K36").Value = Range("J36").Value
    Range("K37").Value = Range("J37").Value
    Range("K38").Value = Range("J38").Value
    Range("K39").Value = Range("J39").Value
    Range("K40").Value = Range("J40").Value
    Range("K41").Value = Range("J41").Value


    Range("K43:O50").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L43").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("K43").Value = Range("J43").Value
    Range("K44").Value = Range("J44").Value
    Range("K45").Value = Range("J45").Value
    Range("K46").Value = Range("J46").Value
    Range("K47").Value = Range("J47").Value
    Range("K48").Value = Range("J48").Value
    Range("K49").Value = Range("J49").Value
    Range("K50").Value = Range("J50").Value

    ws.Activate 'select old worksheet

End Sub
```

Comment: The **&** is used to concatenate text values and the **+** is used for mathematical addition. You shouldn't be trying to sum text-that-looks-like-numbers with padded spaces nor comparing text-that-looks-like-numbers with padded spaces to zero without converting to true numbers with CLng, CDbl, etc..

Comment: Without seeing the "other code" or the data, I'd suspect that your [IsEmpty test isn't doing what you think it is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38518107/4088852).

Comment: please post the rest of your code, also you are missing the `End Function` which I am sure is a typo

Comment: @Jeeped So I need to covert those cells before I can check to see if anything is there?

Comment: Thank you @Comintern, I took out the `IsEmpty` function and it works perfectly now. =D

Answer (score 0):

I took out `IsEmpty` and the code does what I want it to do now.

Thanks @Comintern